# confusion about these sexual acts permissible or not

Tags: halal-haram

Is it permissible to do fingering before having sex with my husband? or even after sex if he is done but I am not over yet?

Is it also permissible not to drop the sperm in vagina to avoid pregnancy?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I don't think the 'avoiding pregnancy' bit is allowed to be honest like I'm not 100% sure but I believe it's only allowed if you are having financial issues, spacing between children, etc